# Javascript object inside an object selection

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, object

How would I go about selecting for example the style contents of an object inside an object etc..

The contents of data is a json encoded array.

In my example I'm using the code data[i].replies and getting 2.. but how would I go about getting data[i].userstyles <- object

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEI6i.png

I'd like to be able to select/ see the contents of style -> `style: "color: #C93030;font-weight:bold;text-shadow: 0 0 6px #C93030;"`

Even when I just insert `data[i].userstyles` it says userstyles is undefined.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userstyle' of undefined is coming back in the console when I try that, I did try that myself.

Comment: turns out it was outside of the loop, worked with 0.. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access it like

```
data[i].userstyle.children[0].children[0].style //should contain "color: #C93030;font-weight:bold;text-shadow: 0 0 6px #C93030;"
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userstyle' of undefined is coming back in the console when I try that

Comment: @user3725340 How are you looping it? Can you replace i with 0 and check?

Comment: oh my, thanks.. i just realised it's outside of the loop.. did work with 0.. appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was outside of my loop so "i" wasn't defined, it worked with replacing "i" with 0.

Thanks for your help guys, rookie mistake.